# Launch a Swift OSX app by dragging and dropping a file or folder on it

Tags: swift, macos, drag-and-drop

I am trying to figure out how to launch a Swift app on OSX by dragging and dropping a file or folder and have it treat the full path to the dropped resource as an argument.

Answer (score 5):

First, select your project in Project Navigator (the root node) and goto the Info tab to declare the file types that your app supports. It can be as narrow as "only CSV files" or as wide as "any file and folder":

[image: Target Info settings]

Next, in your `AppDelegate.swift` file, add `application(_:openFile:)`

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ sender: NSApplication, openFile filename: String) -> Bool {
        print("openning file \(filename)")

        // You must determine if filename points to a file or folder

        // Now do your things...

        // Return true if your app opened the file successfully, false otherwise
        return true
    }
}
```

File types in OS X are determined by a hierarchy of Uniform Type Identifier (UTI). For example, a JPEG file has a UTI of `public.jpeg`, which is subbranch of `public.image`, which is a subbranch of `public.data`, etc. For more information, see [Uniform Type Identifier Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_intro/understand_utis_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001319) and [System-Declared Uniform Type Identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259-SW1).

To find out the UTI hierarchy of a file or folder, use `mdls`:

```
mdls -name kMDItemContentTypeTree /path/to/file_or_folder
```

Comment: Hi, i am trying to achieve something similar. But it is not working for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58458717/how-to-make-my-macos-app-recognize-a-folder-as-a-file-it-can-open   How do i make it so that when i double click a folder (myfolder.extension) it will open my app?